# Example of Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that $f(z)=z\tan(hz)+K$, for some real and positive constants $h,K$, has no zeros in the first quadrant $Q_1$ (i.e. it has no zeros of the form $x+iy$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$). So the Argument Principle says \begin{equation}2\pi i (N-P)=\int\limits_{Q_1} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz\end{equation} where $N$ and $P$ are the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ in $Q_1$ respectively. We know that $f(z)=z\tan(hz)+K$ has no poles in $Q_1$ since the poles of $\tan(hz)$ are $z_n=(n-0.5)\pi/h\in\mathbb{R}\not\subset Q_1$. So the last step (by using $P=0$) is to prove \begin{equation}\int\limits_{Q_1} \frac{\tan(hz)+hz\sec^2(hz)}{z\tan(hz)+K}dz=0\end{equation} Can anybody help me how to prove the equation above?

Comment: You have it upside down.  The integrand should be $\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ instead.

Comment: thanks, i just fixed it. can you still help me with the unanswered question?